# Remove repeated values from the table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a PL/SQL select query like,

```
select 
    a.sgm,
    b.numbr 
from tbl1 a, tbl2 b 
where b.itemId = a.itemId 
    and b.orgId = a.orgId 
    and a.srvCode = 'F' 
    and a.nbrCode <> 1 
    and rownum <= 7
```

Right now it retrieves like ,

```
sgm-|-numbr 
-----------
abc-|-123
abc-|-678
abc-|-78
abc-|-099
bcd-|-153
bcd-|-123
bcd-|-123
```

I need to retrieve like ,

```
sgm-|-numbr 
-----------
abc-|-123
bcd-|-153
```

ie, I need to remove the repeated ones in the first column. ie `sgm` shouldn't repeat.

Comment: What is your criteria for keeping the numbr column?  Keep the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Oracle, then try this simplified version using a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT sgm, numbr, 
      rownum rn
    FROM YourTable 
    )

SELECT CTE.sgm, CTE.numbr
FROM CTE
JOIN (
  SELECT sgm,  MIN(rownum) minrn
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY sgm) t ON CTE.sgm = t.sgm AND CTE.rn = t.minrn
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d6fb/10

You can replace your query in the CTE above.

Good luck.

Comment: But getting `sgm, numbr,rn,sgm,minrn` as fetched. Can we show only `sgm, numbr`.?

Comment: Yep, just change Select * to SELECT CTE.sgm, CTE.numbr -- updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d6fb/11

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.sgm,MAX(b.numbr) 
from tbl1 a, tbl2 b 
where b.itemId = a.itemId 
AND b.orgId= a.orgId 
and a.srvCode= 'F' 
and a.nbrCode <> 1 
and rownum<=7
group by sgm
```

The value of sgm wont repeat, but maximum value of number will be selected, similarly you can also select the minimum value using the Min function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.sgm, MAX(b.numbr) 
FROM tbl1 a INNER JOIN tbl2 b 
    ON a.itemID = b.itemId
    AND a.orgId = b.orgId
WHERE a.srvCode= 'F' 
AND a.nbrCode <> 1 
AND rownum <= 7
GROUP BY a.sgm
```

Apply a group function of your choice like `MAX()` on `b.numbr`, and apply the grouping on `a.sgm`, this should do what you need.

Advice : do your joins explicitly, see the difference between your query and mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a from  tbl a , tbl b WHERE a.userid > b..userid and
a.sgm = b.sgm;
```

Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b8f/2

Answer (score 0):

Use group by function

select 
    a.sgm,
    b.numbr 
from tbl1 a, tbl2 b 
where b.itemId = a.itemId 
    and b.orgId = a.orgId 
    and a.srvCode = 'F' 
    and a.nbrCode <> 1 
    and rownum <= 7
group by a.sgm